# Integration by parts when the two functions are absolutely continuous and continuously differentiable respectively

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

I am doing Exercise 1.6.51 in Terence Tao's introduction to measure theory.

> Let $F : [a, b]\to\mathbb R$ be an absolutely continuous function, and let $\phi: [a, b]\to\mathbb R$ be a continuously
> differentiable function supported in a compact subset of $(a, b)$. Show
> that $\int_{[a,b]}F'\phi(x) \,dx = -\int_{[a,b]}
> F\phi'
> (x)\, dx$.

I made a "proof", as follows, that only requires $\phi$ to be absolutely continuous, instead of being continuously differentiable (which is stronger than absolute continuity in this case).
I believe there's something wrong, but I cannot find it out.
I would be grateful if someone can help.

Below, by integral I mean Lebesgue integral.

Since $F$ and $\phi$ are absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$, we know that $F$ and $\phi$ are integrable, and that $F'$ and $\phi'$ are integrable as functions defined almost everywhere on $[a,b]$.

So both $F'\phi$ and $F\phi'$ are integrable.
Then, we need only show
$$\int_{[a,b]}(F'\phi+F\phi')(x)\,dx=0.$$

At any $x$ where $F$ and $\phi$ are differentiable, we know that $F\phi$ is differentiable with $(F\phi)'(x)=(F'\phi+F\phi')(x)$.
And almost every point in $[a,b]$ is such a point since $F$ and $\phi$ are absolutely continuous.
So we need only show
$$\int_{[a,b]}(F\phi)'(x)\,dx=0.$$

Since $F$ and $\phi$ are absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$, so is $F\phi$.
So the second fundamental theorem gives
$$\int_{[a,b]}(F\phi)'(x)\,dx=(F\phi)(b)-(F\phi)(a),$$
which is indeed $0$ since the support of $\phi$ is a subset of $(a,b)$.

Comment: Your proof is correct and absolute continuity of $\phi$ is enough.

Comment: Thank you for checking my proof!

Comment: You write "Since F and ϕ are absolutely continuous on [a,b], so is Fϕ". Why is this true? I don't think this is quite trivial.

Comment: Suppose they are absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$. Then they are continuous on $[a,b]$. So $|F|,|\phi|$ are bounded  by some $M\in\mathbb R^+$ simultaneously.
Then $$\sum |F(b_i)\phi(b_i)-F(a_i)\phi(a_i)| \le \sum[|F(b_i)\phi(b_i)-F(a_i)\phi(b_i)|+|F(a_i)\phi(b_i)-F(a_i)\phi(a_i)|]\le M\sum [|F(b_i)-F(a_i)|+|\phi(b_i)-\phi(a_i)|].$$

By the absolute continuity of $F,\phi$, this can be arbitrarily small as long as $(a_1,b_1),\dots,(a_n,b_n)$ are disjoint and their total length is small enough.

Comment: This is actually another exercise in Tao's handouts. I should have mentioned this to make my arguments clearer.
Thank you for checking my proof!